# import pyodbc failure mac os

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pyodbc

I've tried to install pyodbc on mac, but I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyodbc
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/unixodbc/lib/libodbc.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

What could it be and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

See if an installation of `unixodbc` helps you:

```
brew install unixodbc
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried all of the above with no luck. Finally I installed version 4.0.34 of pyodbc along with the unixodbc and now all is well.

```
brew install unixodbc  
pip install pyodbc==4.0.34
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Paste this command in MAC terminal if brew not found.
after that -
brew install unixodbc

Comment: It would be great if you can expand your answer on "how" does this fix the issue.